# Custom rating bar?

Tags: android, android-theme, ratingbar

I have a layout.I have embedded a custom rating bar in it:

```
<RatingBar
            android:id="@id/rate"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:max="5"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratebar_theme"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />
```

It is `ratebar_theme`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty_show"/>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty_show"/>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_filled_show"/>

</layer-list>
```

Both `star_empty_show` and `star_filled_show` are `.png` files in `drawable` folder of project.Both above codes have no error,but in `Graphical layout` tab I see this:

```
Failed to parse file E:\...\res\drawable\ratebar_theme.xml
```

And in `Error Log` I see this:

```
  org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #6: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

But I have add `drawable` attribute to each item.Do ypu know why this error occures?

Comment: I didnt understand what error your are getting

Comment: try to clean project, then restart eclipse

Comment: @Janmejoy This error is occured before running App.

Comment: did you clean and run your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Clean your project and restart your eclipse, hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@+android:id/background"
            android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty_show"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
            android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty_show"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+android:id/progress"
            android:drawable="@drawable/star_filled_show"/>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: @StudentStudent its cool, i thought after clean and build also you didnt get thats why i post that...

Comment: you have to remove '+' from `@+android:id` in each item.